# Sudoku solver perfomance issues when implemented in a pygame-application

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pygame, sudoku

Yesterday I created an sudoku solver using backtracking, which, works like its supposed to without performance issues. I decided to create an pygame application, which you with your mouse and keyboard can fill in the cells, and then press the "solve" button to finish the puzzle. I copy pasted the exact code from the Solver-algorithm to the pygame application (which is found in the Solver-class).

In the pygame application you can fill in cells and solve the puzzle most of the times, so it works as its supposed to. However, on more hard puzzles as the one found below, I encounter CPU issues, causing the application to use all of my CPU and eventually crash (im on a Mac OS. HighS system with I5):

[Puzzle from telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/9359579/Worlds-hardest-sudoku-can-you-crack-it.html)

To sum up my problem: 
The sudoku solver algorithm works fine when not called from within the pygame application, (the telegraph puzzle is solved in 2.s roughly), but when called from within the pygame application, it can solve easy puzzles, but the harder ones causes the application to crash due to overuse of CPU.

Heres a picture of the initial setup that causes the crash:
[image]

Code is found below:

```py
class Sudoku():
    def __init__(self):
        self.W,self.H = (600,600)
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.quit()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.W+200,self.H))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.board = Board()
        self.focused = None
        self.solve = Button((0,140,0),650,200,100,50,"Solve")
        self.solver = Solver(self.board.sudoku)
        self.run()

    ### Takes care of pygame events from mouse and keyboard     
    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                self.focused = self.getCellFromMousePos(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                if self.solve.isOver(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    self.solver.solve()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                print("key")
                if self.focused!=None:
                    try:
                        self.board.set_value(self.focused[0],self.focused[1],int(event.unicode))
                    except:
                        pass
    ## Calls paint functions from working units (button, board)
    def paint(self):
        self.screen.fill((255,229,204))
        self.board.paint(self.screen,self.W,self.H)
        self.solve.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    ## Main loop
    def run(self):
        self.running = True

        while self.running:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(60)/1000
            self.update()
    ## Update called from main loop
    def update(self):
        self.events()
        self.paint()
    ## Set value on board (Unused)
    def set_value(self,row,col,value):
        self.board.set_value(row,col,value)
    ## Get a cell (0-9,0-9) from the mouse position.
    def getCellFromMousePos(self,coord):
        return (math.floor(coord[0]/(self.W/9)),math.floor(coord[1]/(self.H/9)))


class Board():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sudoku = [ [0]*9 for _ in range(9) ]
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',81)
    ## Takes a preset board as input - NOT USED
    def set_preset(self,board):
        if len(board)==9 and len(board[1])==9:
            for row in board:
                for cell in row:
                    if board[row][cell]>9 or board[row][cell]<0:
                        return None

            self.sudoku = board
    ## Sets value in a cell
    def set_value(self,row,col,value):
        if self.value_is_valid(value):
            self.sudoku[row][col] = value

    ## Check if an value is valid
    def value_is_valid(self,value):
        if int(value)<=9 and int(value)>=0:
            return True
        return False

    ## Paints grid and numbers to pygame.screen
    def paint(self,screen,width,height):
      ## DRAW background board itself:
        for row in range(10):
            k = row*(height/9)
            pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),(0,k),(width,k))

        for col in range(10):
            k = col*(width/9)
            pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),(k,0),(k,height))

        ## Draw numbers:
        for r in range(9):
            for c in range(9):
                value = self.sudoku[r][c]
                if value != 0:
                    text = self.font.render(str(value),2,(0,0,0))
                    screen.blit(text,((width/9)*r+(text.get_width()/2),(height/9)*c))

## Just a button.
class Button:
    def __init__(self,color,x,y,width,heigth,text):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.heigth = heigth
        self.text = text
        self.color = color

    def draw(self,window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.heigth))

        if self.text!="":
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans',61)
            text = font.render(self.text,2,(0,0,0))
            window.blit(text,(self.x+(self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.heigth/2 -text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self,pos):
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0]< (self.x+self.width):
            if pos[1]> self.y and pos[1]< self.y+self.heigth:
                return True

        return False
## Solving algorithm
class Solver:
    def __init__(self,board):
        self.sudoku = board


    def valid(self,row,column,value):
        original = self.sudoku[row][column]

        self.sudoku[row][column] = value

        validity = self.duplicates()

        self.sudoku[row][column] = original

        return not validity

    ## Checks if an array contains duplicates
    def arrayContainsDuplicates(self,array):
        if len(array) == len(set(array)):
            return False
        return True
    ## Trims an array from empty spaces (0's)
    def trimarray(self,array):
        trimmed = []
        for cell in array:
            if cell != 0:
                trimmed.append(cell)
        return trimmed
    ## Finds the next empty cell. Used for backtracking.
    def find_empty(self):
        for i in range(len(self.sudoku)):
            for j in range(len(self.sudoku[i])):
                if self.sudoku[i][j] == 0:
                    return (i,j)
        return None
    ## Checks if the board contains any duplicates in rows, blocks and columns.
    def duplicates(self):
        for row in self.sudoku:
            if self.arrayContainsDuplicates(self.trimarray(row)):
                return True
        for col in map(list,zip(*self.sudoku)):
            if self.arrayContainsDuplicates(self.trimarray(col)):
                return True

        blocks=[[self.sudoku[int(m//3)*3+i][(m%3)*3+j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)] for m in range(9)]

        for block in blocks:
            if self.arrayContainsDuplicates(self.trimarray(block)):
                return True

        return False
    ## Backtrakcing solving algorithm.
    def solve(self):
        find = self.find_empty()

        if not find:
            return True
        else:
            row,col = find
            for i in range(1,10):
                if self.valid(row,col,i):
                    self.sudoku[row][col] = i

                    if self.solve():
                        return True
                    else:
                        self.sudoku[row][col] = 0

s = Sudoku()
```

Comment: There is no such thing as *'crash due to overuse of CPU'*

Comment: It's in the link posted above, but I have submitted a picture of the initial state of numbers as well :)

Comment: @Finomnis: There is SIGXCPU, but that’s probably not the issue here!

Comment: @DavisHerring lol :D

Comment: @OliverBak sorry for the spam :D but this is quite a big project you have here, I don't think I have the time to read into your entire project right now :/
I read a little bit into it, i think there are two possibilities. 1. The problem is just too big in complexity and the algorithm would finish, it would just take forever, or 2. your recursion is wrong. I don't see anything obviously wrong with it, so maybe your algorithm is just too slow? Btw, there is a `return False` missing as default case ins `solve()`.

Comment: You see, your bruteforce algorithm is pretty good for sudokus that have like 2-3 branches in them. But the 'worlds hardest sudoku' will be artificially generated so that there are as many branches in there as possible, slowing your algorithm down like crazy.

Also, next time, only post the solver, not all your code.

Comment: Yah, from my first tests, it seems like it's working, it's just too slow. Try to optimize it... Writing a fast sudoku solver is not an easy task

Comment: Instead of bruteforcing it, I would compute all the possibilities every cell could have, then take the cell with the least possibilities and iterate through them. That will be a lot faster. If that's still too slow, you will have to write simple combinatory algorithms that try to figure out how multiple cells affect each other, to improve the next 'guess' even further. Have fun!

Comment: I actually managed to make it solve the world hardest sudoku after 10 mins of leaving the computer working. Problem is, that when the algorithm (solver) is ran outside the pygame application, it's solved in 2-10secs roughly, leading me to think there something wrong with my pygame application. Or pygame could just be slowing it down a lot?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solver:

```
known = [ [8,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0],
          [0,0,3, 6,0,0, 0,0,0],
          [0,7,0, 0,9,0, 2,0,0],

          [0,5,0, 0,0,7, 0,0,0],
          [0,0,0, 0,4,5, 6,0,0],
          [0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,3,0],

          [0,0,1, 0,0,0, 0,6,8],
          [0,0,8, 5,0,0, 0,1,0],
          [0,9,0, 0,0,0, 4,0,0]
        ]

import random
groups  = [ p//27*3+p%9//3   for p in range(81) ]
colNums = [ set(range(1,10)) for _ in range(9)  ]
rowNums = [ set(range(1,10)) for _ in range(9)  ]
grpNums = [ set(range(1,10)) for _ in range(9)  ]
sudoku  = [ [0]*9 for _ in range(9) ]
for pos in range(81):
    row,col,group = pos//9,pos%9,groups[pos]
    fixed = known[row][col]
    if fixed:
        sudoku[row][col] = fixed
        colNums[col].discard(fixed)
        rowNums[row].discard(fixed)
        grpNums[group].discard(fixed)

pos        = 0
availables = [ None for _ in range(81)]
while pos < 81:
    row,col,group    = pos//9,pos%9,groups[pos]
    number = sudoku[row][col]
    fixed  = known[row][col]
    if number != 0 and not fixed:
        sudoku[row][col] = 0
        colNums[col].add(number)
        rowNums[row].add(number)
        grpNums[group].add(number)
    if availables[pos] is None:
        availables[pos] = {fixed} if fixed else colNums[col] & rowNums[row] & grpNums[group]
    if availables[pos]:
        number = fixed or min(availables[pos])
        if not fixed:
           sudoku[row][col] = number
           colNums[col].discard(number)
           rowNums[row].discard(number)
           grpNums[group].discard(number)
        availables[pos].discard(number)
        pos += 1
    else:
        availables[pos] = None
        pos -= 1
        if pos < 0 : break

if pos < 81:
    print("FAILED!")            
else :
    for r,line in  enumerate(sudoku):
        print(*[line[i:][:3] for i in range(0,9,3)],"\n"*(r%3==2))
```

It finds a solution in 0.15 sec (excluding printing time):

```
[8, 4, 9] [2, 7, 1] [3, 5, 6] 
[2, 1, 3] [6, 5, 4] [8, 7, 9] 
[6, 7, 5] [8, 9, 3] [2, 4, 1] 

[3, 5, 2] [9, 6, 7] [1, 8, 4] 
[1, 8, 7] [3, 4, 5] [6, 9, 2] 
[9, 6, 4] [1, 8, 2] [7, 3, 5] 

[7, 2, 1] [4, 3, 9] [5, 6, 8] 
[4, 3, 8] [5, 2, 6] [9, 1, 7] 
[5, 9, 6] [7, 1, 8] [4, 2, 3]
```

*Note: it will take up to 4 seconds to figure out that there are no solution if the case may be.  This means that the worst case scenario for an extremely complex problem would be less than 4 seconds.  The world's supposedly [hardest](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/9359579/Worlds-hardest-sudoku-can-you-crack-it.html) was solved in 0.11 seconds )*